# WebAPI with either self-hosted or IIS option

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI that is currently self-hosted.
I also made an IIS version of it as a separate project.

What I want to do is, combine these two projects into one solution and based on a setting I can apply, compile it either as self-hosted or IIS.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having two separate projects in the same solution and the IIS project linking to the files ( models, controllers, services etc.) in the Self-hosted project which seems to work pretty good!

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any concern to use only one hosting model in your IIS?Since switch hosting model need to change hostingmodel attribute and application pool CLR version. So I think host your WebAPI under two different sub-application would be a solution. So that they can use diffferent hosting model and choose different application pools.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/

Comment: This seems only about IIS, if I'm not mistaken. I also want to use the self-hosted model.

Comment: out-of-process also works as self-hosting with dotnet.exe and kestrel. IIS just works as a proxy. If it is not acceptable then it is hard to switch dotnet and w3wp.exe.